# Can weapon special abilities that don't say they're passed on to ammunition be added to ranged weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Certain weapon special abilities in *D&D 3.5* can sensibly be applied to melee or ranged weapons yet are not listed in the random roll table for magical ranged weapons, only melee, and do not state that they pass their special ability on to their ammunition. Take, for instance, *[dancing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#dancing)*:

> **Dancing**
>   As a standard action, a dancing weapon can be loosed to attack on its own. It 
>   fights for 4 rounds using the base attack bonus of the one who loosed it and 
>   then drops. While dancing, it cannot make attacks of opportunity, and the 
>   person who activated it is not considered armed with the weapon. In all other 
>   respects, it is considered wielded or attended by the creature for all 
>   maneuvers and effects that target items. While dancing, it takes up the same 
>   space as the activating character and can attack adjacent foes (weapons with 
>   reach can attack opponents up to 10 feet away). The dancing weapon accompanies 
>   the person who activated it everywhere, whether she moves by physical or 
>   magical means. If the wielder who loosed it has an unoccupied hand, she can 
>   grasp it while it is attacking on its own as a free action; when so retrieved 
>   the weapon can’t dance (attack on its own) again for 4 rounds.
>
> Strong transmutation; CL 15th; Craft Magic Arms and Armor, *animate objects*; Price +4 bonus.

And [*wounding*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#wounding):

> **Wounding**
>   A wounding weapon deals 1 point of Constitution damage from blood loss when it 
>   hits a creature. A critical hit does not multiply the Constitution damage. 
>   Creatures immune to critical hits (such as plants and constructs) are immune 
>   to the Constitution damage dealt by this weapon.
>
> Moderate evocation; CL 10th; Craft Magic Arms and Armor, *mage’s sword*; Price +2 bonus.

Can you make a *dancing composite longbow* or a *wounding sling* by the RAW or are those things that would require a special exemption from the DM?  Or would the *wounding* weapon special ability need to be applied explicitly to the sling's bullets, such as is the case for the weapon special ability [*spell storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring) to the best of my understanding?

Comment: What exactly do you expect a dancing arrow to do? That does not seem useful. A dancing *bow*, now, that's a fine idea, but I don't see why that would need to pass it on to its ammunition.

Comment: @TuggyNE -- I agree, a dancing bow doesn't need to pass its enchantment onto its ammunition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unless a magic weapon special ability says so, a weapon special ability *isn't* bestowed upon a weapon's ammunition

Magic items—like feats, spells, and other effects—do *only* what they say they do unless the DM says otherwise. Thus if a weapon special ability does not *say* that the weapon special ability is bestowed upon its ammunition, the weapon with that weapon special ability does *not* bestow that weapon special ability upon its ammunition.

However, that doesn't prevent the *existence* of weapons like the *+1 [dancing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#dancing) longbow*, the *+1 [wounding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#wounding) crossbow*, or the *+1 [spell storing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring) sling*, but those weapon special abilities when applied to those weapons apply *only* to the weapons themselves rather than to the ammunition they launch; usually this means if wielders want those special abilities to take effect the weapons must be used as [improvised weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#improvisedWeapons) (*PH* 113).

Addressing these examples, a loosed *+1 dancing longbow* smacks folks on its own as if the wielder were using it as an improvised weapon, a wizard who successfully bashes a bear with his *+1 wounding crossbow* does so using the crossbow as an improvised weapon but nonetheless magically wounds the bear, and when the halfling outrider slaps his mount with his *+1 spell storing sling* the outrider can take a free action to cast on his mount the spell stored within that sling. (Slapping even an allied creature with a *+1 spell storing sling* is still using the sling as an improvised weapon.)

#### The *Dungeon Master's Guide*'s tables don't tell the whole story

When making a case for limiting weapon special abilities to certain weapons, proponents often point to Table 7–14: Melee Weapon Special Abilities and Table 7–15: Ranged Weapon Special Abilities and say that if a weapon special ability *doesn't* appear on the appropriate table that weapon special ability *can't* be placed on weapons of that type. However, the reason these tables are present is for

> **Random Generation:** To generate magic weapons randomly, first roll on Table 7–9: Weapons, and then roll on Table 7–10: Weapon Type Determination. Use Table 7–14: Melee Weapon Special Abilities, Table 7–15: Ranged Weapon Special Abilities, or Table 7–16: Specific Weapons if indicated by the roll on Table 7–9. (*DMG* 223)

So if *not* generating magic weapons randomly, the tables go unused.

What the tables are *actually* doing is preventing the DM from being a jerk. See, when the DM is randomly generating a creature's treasure, he rolls on Table 7–9: Weapons to determine the weapon's enhancement bonus, then on Table 7–10: Weapon Type Determination (yielding a 70% chance of a melee weapon, 20% chance of a ranged weapon, and a 10% chance of an uncommon weapon); then on the kind-of-weapon Tables 7–11, 7–12, or 7–13; then, *finally*, on the appropriate melee weapon special ability or ranged weapon special ability table (Table 7–14 or 7–15). Because Table 7–13: Common Ranged Weapons includes *both* ammunition *and* the weapons using ammunition, *every* weapon special ability on Table 7–15: Ranged Weapon Special Abilities *must* be compatible with both ranged weapons *and* their ammunition.<sup>1</sup>

Were there but a *lone* table for randomly determining weapon special abilities, the DM would *either* roll until getting an effective combination *or* laugh maniacally as he generated stupid weapons suitable only as vendor trash. For example, the tables prevent the DM from randomly generating loot piles containing *+1 disruption longbows* (which unleash their destructive power against undead when such longbows are used as improvised weapons) or *+1 speed arrows* (which give an extra attack when used as improvised weapons). The tables for random treasure generation are actually kind of spiffy that way.<sup>2</sup>

> #### Curious Case #1: [*Defending*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring)
>
> The weapon special ability [*defending*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#defending) says
>
> > A *defending* weapon allows the wielder to transfer some or all of the **sword**’s enhancement bonus to his AC as a bonus that stacks with all others. As a free action, the wielder chooses how to allocate the weapon’s enhancement bonus at the start of his turn before using the weapon, and the effect to AC lasts until his next turn. (*DMG* 224)
>
> Emphasis mine. Other *defending* weapons notwithstanding (e.g. the *[dagger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#dagger) of defense* (*AE* 104) (58,302 gp; 1 lb.); the [dwarven waraxe](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#waraxeDwarven) *Gharriakha, the Hearthwarden* (*RS* 165) (61,830 gp; 8 lbs.)), the *defending* weapon special ability is, according to the rules as written, limited to swords, and has been so limited throughout the entirety of *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*, including in the premium edition *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2013).
>
> #### Curious Case #2: [*Spell storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring)
>
> The most contentious of weapon special abilities, the weapon special ability [*spell storing*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#spellStoring) says that
>
> > Any time the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it, the weapon can immediately cast the spell on that creature as a free action if the **wielder** desires. (*DMG* 225)
>
> Emphasis mine. Thus the DM must determine if ammunition and thrown weapons, after being loosed, are still wielded. You can read more about the controversy surrounding the weapon special ability *spell storing* in these threads from [2002](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?31242-Arrows-of-Spell-Storing), [2006](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2h5mw?Spell-Storing-Bow), [2008](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?411100-D-amp-D-3-5-Archer-build/page5), [2012](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?227636-Spell-Storing-bolts-arrows!-here-we-go-again), and also [2012](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=7089.0).

The tables for *randomly generating* treasure don't prevent DMs from *placing* (rather than randomly generating) appropriate magic weapons nor do the tables prevent the PCs from *creating* appropriate magic weapons. For example, *+1 [keen](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#keen) crossbow bolts* and *+1 [disruption](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#disruption) sling bullets* are equally legit, as are usually dumb weapons like the aforementioned *+1 dancing longbow et al.*

#### To avoid arguments, put magic weapon special abilities in the format used by the *Magic Item Compendium*

Prior to the *Magic Item Compendium* (Mar. 2007) magic weapon special abilities were not, as part of their typical descriptions, called out as limited to either ammunition, melee weapons, ranged weapons, or a combination of these. Authors and editors were relied upon to remember to have weapon special abilities apply to appropriate weapons. This sometimes led to omissions, mistakes, and strangeness. For example, the weapon special ability *smoking* (+1 bonus) (*Lords of Darkness* 180), as written, can be applied to any weapon but is potentially unbalancing and probably changes the DM's view of his setting significantly when every character who can afford one wields a *+1 smoking crossbow bolt* (166 gp 1 sp; 0.1 lbs.).

After the *Magic Item Compendium*, a weapon special ability's description includes the entry *Property* which specifies the type of item to which the weapon special ability can be applied (e.g. ammunition, melee weapon, weapon).<sup>3</sup> (A similar history applies to armor and shield special abilities.) But, as *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* ceased publication only about a year after the *Magic Item Compendium*, this leaves the vast majority of weapon special abilities unspecified as to what they can be applied except in their description.

I suggest that if you've a particular weapon special ability you want to use dating from before the *Magic Item Compendium* you put it in a format similar to the *Magic Item Compendium*'s and submit it to the DM for review. He'll appreciate you doing the extra work, and, after it's approved, you and he can *really* be on the same page as to how and on what it functions.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The *DMG* implies that ammunition are weapons; if not, the only weapon special ability available for ammunition is [*brilliant energy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#brilliantEnergy) (*DMG* 224).
<sup>**2**</sup> Random generation doesn't wholly prevent stupid weapons. For example, the DM can still roll a *+5 [brilliant energy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#brilliantEnergy) [returning](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#returning) [net](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#net)*.
<sup>**3**</sup> For comparison, *Dungeonscape* (Feb. 2007) contains the weapon special ability *swarmstrike* (+1 bonus) (*Du* 40), which is unclear as to whether *swarmstrike* ranged weapons bestow that special ability on their ammunition, *implying* they do but never stating so, but *Drow of the Underdark* (May 2007) has several magic weapon special abilities, all of which are clear as to what they can be applied and when a ranged weapon bestows the special ability on its ammunition.

Answer (score 2):

**NOT according to SRD/DMG**

SRD/DMG explicitly states (in tables) that these 2 properties are "[Melee Weapon Special Abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#tableMeleeWeaponSpecialAbilities)".

There is another table right below it that has a list of "[Ranged Weapon Special Abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm#tableRangedWeaponSpecialAbilities)".

That said, one of D&Ds greatest attributes is that there are tons of Splat books & magazines available, any of which could possibly expand the SRD original list to include them.  Sadly, the MIC is **NOT** one of them.

*Personal Note: As a DM, I'd allow a wounding ranged weapon. Sounds cool and not overpowered.*

*Clarification from comments: Why would someone with the Craft Magic Arms and Armor feat care which weapon special abilities could be randomly determined? Probably for the same reason someone with the Craft Wonderous Item feat doesn't make a shirt pocket a "bag of holding". Even though it makes sense the rules don't allow it. (But now I totally want a *shirt* of holding)

Comment: Are you implying that a DM, acting according to the SRD's RAW, cannot generate enchanted weapons other than what the SRD random roll tables allow for?

Comment: The rules explicitly states the DM, is able & ENCOURAGED to "Rule 0" anything that improves their game. So, I would do that; however, if the DM wanted to go explicitly RAW then unless your playing with additional material, sadly the core/SRD says those listed are the only ones available.

Comment: Just got home going to check my MIC to see if it has a different answer

Comment: @HeyICanChan, hence why I said I'd "rule 0" it. However, the OP asked & tagged ? as RAW, so I gave a RAW answer with my caveat at the bottom

Comment: @Ben-Jamin Players, of course, can still generate such treasure via crafting feats or utilize an NPC with crafting feats to craft other things.  It's just 'treasure' that can't be generated otherwise, I believe.

Comment: I think yall are missing my point of the tables. The tables are not what's restricting the creation, the tables are only listing items that are eligible to be applied to those types of weapons based on the text. So @thedarkwanderer, yes they could if it wasn't again the creation rules. Just like they can't create a "shirt of holding" they can't create magic weapons that the book doesn't allow.

Answer (score 0):

1) Can we add *Wounding*/*Dancing* to a ranged weapon?

Our feat says:

> You can create any magic weapon, armor, or shield whose prerequisites you meet.

The prerequisites in general do not restrict weapon type

In the magic weapon section we read first that:

> In addition to an enhancement bonus, weapons may have special abilities.

and later, and more specifically:

> In addition to enhancement bonuses, weapons can have one or more of the special abilities detailed below.

Below this last section of text (and on the next several pages) are detailed a number of special abilities, some of which indicate that they may only be placed on a ranged weapon or only on a melee weapon or other various restrictions.  Also near this section happens to be the tables for randomly generating magic weapons as treasure.  The tables do not detail the special abilities, and do not limit the creation of items to be narrower than the broader cannon allowed by the above text.

*Wounding* in particular states nothing about being limited to melee weapons only.  It can thus be placed on ranged weapons.

*Dancing* ranged weapons can attack only adjacent foes while dancing, but they can be made.

So the answer to 1) is **yes**, but *dancing* is obviously of extremely limited utility.

2) Do *wounding* and *dancing* transfer to ammunition when the weapon when fired?

No.  Conferring magic onto ammunition is specified per ability when relevant.  Neither of these abilities make mention of such an effect, so no such effect occurs.  This renders *wounding* pretty much useless unless you plan on bashing people to death with your bow.  *Dancing* still functions fine, but since they can only fire into adjacent squares they are of extremely limited utility and probably not worth the exorbitant price.

You can certainly make *wounding* arrows, however, and these will function just fine.

Also, if you could find a typo in another ranged weapon special ability somewhere, wherein the description conferred the entirety of a ranged weapons enchantments onto its ammunition instead of very carefully specifying that it only transfers the specific ability in question, you could just use that to transfer whatever enchantments you wanted.  No such error exists in the core rules, though.