# Is ammunition considered a weapon for enchantment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, ammunition

Can you put enchantments made for weapon on ammunition or is it strictly ammunition enchantments? 
Ex. The Fiercebane enchantment (MIC p.35) calls out for a weapon slot to be enchanted and says "A fiercebane weapon excels at attacking"

Comment: Ammunition enchantments are distinct because they are nearly Always used with a weapon (bow, crossbow) that can take the weapon enchantments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For the purposes of applying magic weapon special abilities, ammunition is generally considered a weapon

That is, for the purposes of magic weapon special abilities, *weapons* includes *ammunition*. Were this not the case and ammunition must be specifically mentioned by a weapon special ability for that weapon special ability to apply to ammunition, the only *Dungeon Master's Guide* magic weapon special ability that can be applied to ammunition is [*brilliant energy*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#brilliant-energy) (*DMG* 224) (+4 bonus; 0 lbs.). Further, the *Magic Item Compendium* gives each magic weapon special ability a *Property* entry describing onto what the magic weapon special ability can be placed, and no *Property* entry specifies ammunition. (A strict DM could, instead, read this near silence as limiting ammunition to *only* enhancement bonuses and the weapon special ability *brilliant energy*, but I'm not sure why a DM *would*, especially since such specialty ammunition can be randomly generated using the *DMG*'s own tables and Wizards of the Coast's own published creatures employ specialty ammunition.)

Note that some specific magic weapon special abilities can't—for a variety of reasons—be placed on some or all kinds of ammunition and that some—[but far from all](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59727/8610)—specific magic weapon special abilities are passed on to the ammunition by the magical projectile weapon from which the ammunition's launched.

Finally, note that the weapon special ability *fiercebane* (*Magic Item Compendium* 35) (+1 bonus; 0 lbs.) has the notation synergy (explained on *MIC* 224–5), so *fiercebane* ammunition must first have the weapon special ability [*bane*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#bane) (*DMG* 224) (+1 bonus; 0 lbs.): a *+1 fiercebane arrow* has a [+3 enhancement bonus equivalent](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#table-weapons).

Comment: While not answering the question asked, I think it's noteworthy most ammunition is destroyed by using it (or potentially destroyed even by missing) so enchanting ammunition has always seemed a very expensive option to me.

Comment: @joedragons It *is* expensive, but, as weapon special abilities on ammunition apply in many cases *in addition* to weapon special abilities granted by the projectile weapon, sometimes something needs to get shot *hard*,  and a couple of units of magical ammunition (if they can be bought piecemeal) are good for that.

Comment: Hence the quiver of infinite *enchanted* arrows.

Comment: @nijineko [So, so expensive!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101395/8610) And what if you then have the wrong kind of magic *quiver*?!

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well, since the one quiver can switch out the material of the arrows, just make one that has different types of enchanted ammunition that you can switch out with. Maybe pick that one shadow spell that is ever so flexible... ^^ That, or use *Hank's Energy Bow* since it was given 3.x stats.